# What is a "Y" shaped bolt called?

Tags: hardware

I am trying to recreate a folding artist's stool shown on the Mr. Rogers show. It requires a Y shaped bolt, which I can't find anywhere. I have been searching for "Y bolt" with no luck. Does it have a different name?

[image]

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Tandy-Leather-Tri-Bolt-Nickel-1189-00/dp/B01M4LBHD0.  Shopping questions are off topic but a quick google search led me to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for "tri bolt".  These are somewhat standard hardware although I've never seen one at a big-box store.